# Website justed ignored all media queries on mobile

Tags: css, media-queries

Website I've been working on just started ignoring all media queries.  I can't seem to find the problem.

http://fnd.instinctdigitalmedia.com/

On the homepage the images under the 'Browse our Products" section shoud change based on screen width. at 320px, 480px, and 768px screen width it still shows the originals.

Comment: Think you may be missing the `and`.  `@media only screen AND (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

You must target the ancestor or parent to override what the previous query has done.
From 760px to override its style rule you should add call the parent #content of the img to override the rule in 760px

Example:
     
        
           
        
     #content > img {width:25%;}
    }

```
@media screen and (max-width : 480px){
   #content > img {width:50%;}
}

@media screen and (max-width : 760px){
    img {width:100%;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a few issues I can see. Firstly, media queries aren't firing because:

There's a closing parenthese missing on line 899, flipping an error. To find this, I added my own media query showing something obvious, and pasted it at the top of the CSS, then further and further down until it stopped working.

Also, the mobile view failed because you are missing 'and' in your media query:

```
@media only screen (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {}
```

It should be:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {
```

As for the width break itself, a handy trick with responsive designs is to limit this kind of issue from ever occurring before you even start styling (this is a rough guide, not a comprehensive list):

```
img, video, object, iframe, fieldset, table, form, article, section, header, nav, footer {
    max-width:100% !important;
}
```

Even when respecifying the widths of your images, you are still using pixel widths instead of a relative measurement like `percentages`. This means the images will stay a static size and won't resize correctly to the screen no matter what.

Lastly, you are using a 'bracketed' approach for your media queries. This means rather than allowing your existing CSS to cascade down your media queries, saving you having to specify things twice that aren't going to change, you must repeat the same code many times.

For example, you currently have:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .product-cat-1 {
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
        width: 430px;
        height: 150px;
        background-image: url('http://localhost/firstnations/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/home-lighting.jpg');
    }
}
```

Anything below `768px` must be specified all over again. This leads to massive amounts of repeated code, and a lot of extra work for you. The simpler approach would be:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    /* all styles for under 1024px  */
}
```

Then for anything smaller:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    /* only styles that need to change when under 768px wide */
}
```